# How do I trigger/capture an event from my PHP generate HTML Code?

Tags: php, html

My class...

```
<?php

class SelectionBoxbuilder
{
    public function RenderToHTML()

    {
        $SelectBox = '<select>
                        <option>"One"</option>
                        <option>"Two"</option>
                            </select>';

            return $SelectBox;


        }

    }
```

My PHP test file that generates the selection box...

```
<?php


foreach (glob("classes/*.php") as $filename)
{
    include $filename;
}

$sb = new SelectionBoxbuilder();

echo $sb->RenderToHTML();
```

This Works, but I need to know how to capture the event from the Selection box I have generated, not sure if I am in fact approaching this from the wrong angle perhaps I need to do this in an entirely different manner?

I basically want the event to trigger some other PHP code I have not written yet and pass the value of the selection box as a parameter.

Hope this I clear enough if not please let me know any additional information I could add.

So...

When the user changes the item selected on the selection box I would like this to trigger an event, which I will then 'point' to some other PHP code.

Comment: What event are you talking about?

Comment: Im not entirely sure what your trying to do, but I've found this to be the most effective method

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are talking about change events on the select box (i.e. when the user selects a different value).

The main thing you need to understand is that the event is fired on the client side in the browser, while your PHP code is running on the server. It has no way of knowing what's happening on the client.

If you need to do something in PHP when these events are fired, you can add JavaScript code to handle the client-side event and to fire an AJAX request to your server-side PHP script.

Comment: yes this is correct I have amended the question will some more info regarding the event. Perhaps a bit much to ask you what code to put where? If so I could go away and research on JavaScript/AJAX. :)

Comment: @user3755946 I'm afraid you should go away and research JavaScript and Ajax.  Sorry for being so bland, but SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

In basicly PHP is a server side language.
So after the server side send output to browser you can't use PHP anymore.

To get the selection from user you need to make a new request to server.

You can do it by two methods:

1. Send the form data to server by regular http request (GET/POST).
2. Send data with ajax request for UX reasons.

First you need to change your "SelectionBoxbuilder" class to form element.
Like this:

```
<?php
class SelectionBoxbuilder{
    public function RenderToHTML(){
        $SelectBox = '
            <form method="post">
                <select name="selectbox">
                    <option value="1">"One"</option>
                    <option value="2">"Two"</option>
                </select>
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Send" />
            </form>
        ';

        return $SelectBox;
    }

}
```

Now you have a form in you HTML output.

To get the response we need to add handler for the post request to the test file:

```
<?php

foreach (glob("classes/*.php") as $filename){
    include $filename;
}

$sb = new SelectionBoxbuilder();

// If form submited
if( isset( $_POST['selectbox'] ) ){
    echo 'Your selection is: ' . $_POST['selectbox'];
}

echo $sb->RenderToHTML();
```

You can add new method to your class to take care of the response:

```
<?php
class SelectionBoxbuilder{
    public function RenderToHTML(){
        $SelectBox = '
            <form method="post">
                <select name="selectbox">
                    <option value="1">"One"</option>
                    <option value="2">"Two"</option>
                </select>
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Send" />
            </form>
        ';

        return $SelectBox;
    }

    //Check response and return the value if form already submit
    public function checkForResponse(){
        if( isset( $_POST['selectbox'] ) ){
            return 'Your selection is: ' . $_POST['selectbox'];
        }

        // return false if form not send
        return false;
    }

}
```

And now in test file you can do somthing like this:

```
<?php

foreach (glob("classes/*.php") as $filename){
    include $filename;
}

$sb = new SelectionBoxbuilder();

// If form submited
if( $userAnswer = $sb -> checkForResponse() ){
    echo 'Your selection is: ' . $userAnswer;
} else {
    echo $sb->RenderToHTML();
}
```

I hope I was helpful to you.

Comment: thanks for this I am finishing up for the day will try it tomorrow. :)